# How to set Chart dimensions to change as per given data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi i am new to d3js so i am trying out simple example codes

so here's the code

```
d3.selectAll("div")
    .data([100,180,200,400,450])
    .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .style("width", function(d) { return  d +"px"; });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YjED4/

what i want to achieve is set the size of the chart dynamically to the length of the max data that i am passing i.e charts max length should be on a max scale of 0-500 given the max data i have passed is 450

the problem is when i pass data like

```
.data([1,18,20,40,4])
```

i get a chart like this

http://jsfiddle.net/NnLU9/

which beats the purpose of the chart.

So any pointers on how to proceed on this will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D3 is an amazing technology and I hope you stick with it.

The problem with your code is that it does not have a concept of an x-axis or y-axis, your code just has data that change the width by pixels.  Without an x or y axis your chart will not scale properly.

You need something like this in your code:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
    .range([0, 420]);
```

The code snippet states that the values are from 0 to the max of the data set, and the pixel range is from 0 pixels to 420 pixels.  So if your max is 40, then 40 will map to 420 pixels.

Then the following will scale your chart:

```
d3.select(".chart")
  .selectAll("div")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("div")
    .style("width", function(d) { return x(d) + "px"; })
    .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

notice the code that says `return x(d) + 'px'`, what is does is when you pass a value let's say '20' into the function x(d) it will scale it to whatever you had scaled your x-axis to.  So '20' will be 210 pixels in the function above, '0' would be 0 pixels, and '40' would be '420' pixels.

This is the example I used to get started in d3, I think Mike Bostock can explain it better than anyone: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/

Hope this helps.

Comment: what does 
.enter().append("div") 
do?

Comment: D3 is based around 3 concepts: enter, update, exit.  These correspond to when data is bound and updated.  'enter' contains the data to enters the data set, 'update' contains the data that was in the data set and got a new value, 'exit' contains the data that was in the dataset and was removed.  Going those examples for the bar charts will explain a lot.